# Align bottom border of navbar with content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like to have a bottom separator of the navbar that aligns with the rest of the page. Like Refactoring UI did [here](https://miro.medium.com/max/2000/1*rKxhE_48k5x3rI_Gci38sA.png)

However when I add a border to my container inside the navbar it extends outside the content like [so](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l5y03viurh2adi1/Screenshot%202019-08-19%2016.25.34.png?dl=1).

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container" style="border-bottom: 3px solid blue;">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index...
```

I could add a container outside the navbar-element and add a `<hr>` element in there, but that seems bad practice.

What is an elegant and "right" way to add a horizontal separator to the navbar that aligns with the content on the rest of the page?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `row` element and add your styling to it instead of to your `container` this could solve your problem.

Example:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 3px solid blue;">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index...
```

The `row` will have `15px` of padding on the left and right side. It should reduce the width of the `border-bottom` now that the div is nested.

Option two (to not change the layout of elements underneath):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 3px solid blue;"></div>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index...
```

Or you can resort back to a custom style `<hr>` and I don't see anything wrong with that option.

Comment: This does reduce the width of the `border-bottom`, thank you!
However, wrapping all other elements inside the `<div class="row">` element messes up other things. For example elements like `ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">` do not align the elements on the right anymore...

Comment: The second option doesn't work unfortunately. The border of the row doesn't show and the elements outside the row get pushed further to the left and right.

Comment: You can try `<div class="row w-100" style="border-bottom: 3px solid blue;"></div>` followed by a new open row div

Answer (score 0):

You should do it at the nav tag rather than other divisions because by doing that you can change the margins for all the content and the navigation at the same time and align it in same  way.

```css
.content
{
margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="content">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg"  style="border-bottom: 3px solid blue;">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">new
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">new
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">new
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">new
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">new
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">new
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">new
    </a>
  </div>
  </nav>
  <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p></div>
```

Comment: Applying the border at the navbat tag makes it go all the way to each side. However, I want the border to align nicely with the content in other containers outside the navbar.

Comment: @Fabian you need to use padding in order to align it with other content but doing it at nav tag is the good way to implement

Comment: Do you mean something like:
`<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg"  style="border-bottom: 3px solid blue; padding: 0 100px 0 100px">` ?
This doesn't change the length of the element, including the border. It just moves the contents further right or left

Comment: @Fabian Not like that. I have updated the post and see the  margin every element gets equal and aligns correctly.